# Prevent text from moving behind image

Tags: html, css, text, image

I have a page with an image on the left side, and text on the right. When the browser window is resized, or a smaller resolution is used, the text goes behind the image. I want the text to always be beside of the image, and not go behind it.

Any suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/TYpCq/ (The layout on jsfiddle is a bit off. Nevermind this, I just need to know how to prevent the text going behind the image)

HTML:

```
<div id="indishopmain">

<p><strong>Test shop image</strong> by <strong>no one</strong></p>

<div id ="canvasshopwrap">
<div id="canvasshophead">
<p>Blabla</p>
</div>

<div id="canvasshoptext"</p>
<p>The high-quality print on a <span style="color:#01A07E;font-family:Cusmyrb;">stretched canvas</span> lets the artwork just pop of the wall, it’s almost magical. It’s easy to hang up and will keep it’s color brillance as well as the shape for a long time. We are sure, you will love it forever. Note: the size 20 x 20cm comes with a complementary easel.</p>
</div>

</div>

<div id="indishopimg">
<img src="frontgallery/1.jpg" alt="gallery image 1" width="500px" />
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#indishopmain {
    width:100%;
    padding:0em;

}

#indishopmain p {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Logo;
    color:#343234;
    margin-top:4em;
    font-size:90%;
}

#indishopimg img {
    margin-top:-11.9em;
    margin-left:10%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10x #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
}

#canvasshophead {
    display:inline-block;
    width:11em;
    background-color:#5020B8;
    height:2em;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
}

#canvasshophead p {
    font-family:Cusmyrb;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:2;
    margin-top:0;
}

#canvasshopwrap {
    margin-left:60%;
    width:11em;
    display:inline-block;
}

#canvasshoptext p {
    font-family:Cusmyr;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#343234;
    text-align:left;    
}

#canvasshoptext {
    width:11em;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `width: 100%` on the main content wrapper? are you trying to build something that degrades fluidly into smaller devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what it is you're trying to accomplish (things in your code make me wonder if they are by design or not) I will assume you're trying to have a static element centered in the middle of the page. If you're going for a fluid layout (something that will automatically degrade into mobile devices for instance) the solution will look different.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RbA92/

I find that adding temporary background colors to elements can be very helpful when debugging. For the purpose of this exercise I've left them in there for you so you can easily see what's going on. I would also suggest putting these colors on your original fiddle (and change margin to padding to REALLY see what's going on). You had a few things in there that weren't behaving as you intended... I think :)

Here's a little breakdown of the styles for you. I commented out the styles I "removed" and annotated the things I added and why.

```
body { text-align: center; } /* centers all content */

#indishopmain {
    padding:0em;
    /*width: 100%;*/
background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden; /* allows us to float elements inside a non-floated element */
    width: 700px; /* gives the browser a literal size to render, which keeps the elements from moving when the window is resized */
    text-align: left; /* keeps child elements from inheriting the text-aling: center we put on the body */
    margin: 0 auto; /* this is what actually centers our item. use this with body {text-align: center;} */
}

#indishopmain p {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Logo;
    color:#343234;
    margin-top:4em;
    font-size:90%;
}

#indishopimg img {
    /*margin-top:-11.9em;
    margin-left:10%;*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10x #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
    float: left; /* float this bad boy all the way to the left */
}

#canvasshopwrap {
    /*margin-left:60%;*/
    width:11em; /* having this in em could break your layout. consider putting this in px to keep it from getting too big for it's area and being pushed to the bottom */
    /*display:inline-block;*/
background-color: red;
    float: right; /* float this one all the way to the right */
}

#canvasshophead {
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    width:11em;
    background-color:#5020B8;
    /*height:2em;*/
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    padding: 0  0 .5em 0; /* it's better to size the CONTENT how you want, so this box will always contain it. size thie box but leave the contents dynamic and you could end up with the content outside of your container */
}

#canvasshophead p {
    font-family:Cusmyrb;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:2em;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:2;
    margin:0; /* remove any browser-specific formatting */
    padding: 0;  /* ditto */
}

#canvasshoptext {
    width:11em;
}

#canvasshoptext p {
    font-family:Cusmyr;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#343234;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 0;  /* remove any browser-specific formatting */
    margin: 0;  /* ditto */
}
```

Hopefully this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for. Makes sense, just got frustrated in the end I guess and needed some help :) It's kind of a fluid layout, not for mobile devices though, just for adapting to different browser resolutions. On this page, it works out fine that the image is fixed. 

Thanks for the help and your time!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this margin-top:

```
#indishopimg img {
    margin-top:-11.9em;     <--- here
    margin-left:10%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10x #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
}
```

If you want the image beside the text, move the image into the paragraph containing the text and add `float:left` to the CSS above.

Comment: Did you change your HTML as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, like this: <div id="canvasshoptext">  
<p><img src="frontgallery/1.jpg" alt="gallery image 1" width="500px" />The high-quality print on a <span style="color:#01A07E;font-family:Cusmyrb;">stretched canvas</span> lets the artwork just pop of the wall, it’s almost magical. It’s easy to hang up and will keep it’s color brillance as well as the shape for a long time. We are sure, you will love it forever. Note: the size 20 x 20cm comes with a complementary easel.</p>
</div>

Comment: OK, your image is no longer inside "indishopimg" so the CSS rule you made for it no longer applies. Put class="leftImage" in the IGM tag and change the above CSS to be ".leftimage" instead of "#indishopimg img".

Comment: The text is still under the image... Can you try to do the edit in the jsfiddle?